# Try catch block doesn't run

Tags: java, try-catch, saml-2.0, opensaml

Leaving aside the errors in the code that may exist, it is normal, I am a newbie with saml security. I have a problem with a "try/catch" block that doesn't seem to be executed, at least I don't see a trace in the log.
This is my code:

```
        Credential credential = null;
        final MetadataCredentialResolver metadataCredentialResolver = new MetadataCredentialResolver();
        logger.info("Creando key resolver");
        final KeyInfoCredentialResolver keyResolver = DefaultSecurityConfigurationBootstrap.buildBasicInlineKeyInfoCredentialResolver();
        RoleDescriptorResolver roleDescriptorResolver = null;
        logger.info("Reciviendo metadatos");
        
//This try is not working
        try {
            File metadataFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("IDPMetadata.xml").toURI());
            logger.info("Metadata recividos");
            final FilesystemMetadataResolver metadataResolver = new FilesystemMetadataResolver(metadataFile);
            roleDescriptorResolver = new BasicRoleDescriptorResolver(metadataResolver);
            logger.info("Metadata resolver creado");
            metadataResolver.setId(metadataResolver.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            logger.info("Asignada la id");
            metadataResolver.setParserPool(OpenSAMLUtils.getParserPool());
            logger.info("Parse Pool asignado");
            metadataResolver.initialize();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        logger.info("metadata resueltos");
        metadataCredentialResolver.setKeyInfoCredentialResolver(keyResolver);
        metadataCredentialResolver.setRoleDescriptorResolver(roleDescriptorResolver);
        try {
            metadataCredentialResolver.initialize();
        }catch(ComponentInitializationException e){
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        logger.info("Credenciales adquiridas");
        CriteriaSet criteriaSet = new CriteriaSet();
        criteriaSet.add(new UsageCriterion(UsageType.SIGNING));
        criteriaSet.add(new EntityRoleCriterion(SPSSODescriptor.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME));
        criteriaSet.add(new ProtocolCriterion(SAMLConstants.SAML20P_NS));
        criteriaSet.add(new EntityIdCriterion(SPConstants.SP_ENTITY_ID));
        logger.info("Generando credenciales");
        try {
            credential = metadataCredentialResolver.resolveSingle(criteriaSet);
        }catch(ResolverException e){
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        logger.info("Credenciales creadas");
        return credential;
    }
```

And this is my log:

```
10:57:58,689 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.SAML.SAMLConsumer] (default task-1) Verificando firma
10:57:58,690 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.SAML.SAMLConsumer] (default task-1) adquiriendo firma
10:57:58,693 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.SAML.SAMLConsumer] (default task-1) org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.impl.SignatureImpl@4cdd2a52
10:57:58,695 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.util.IDPCredentials] (default task-1) Creando key resolver
10:57:58,697 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.util.IDPCredentials] (default task-1) Reciviendo metadatos
10:57:58,698 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.util.IDPCredentials] (default task-1) metadata resueltos
10:57:58,698 INFO  [org.opensaml.saml.security.impl.MetadataCredentialResolver] (default task-1) RoleDescriptorResolver was not supplied, credentials may only be resolved via RoleDescriptorCriterion
10:57:58,698 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.util.IDPCredentials] (default task-1) Credenciales adquiridas
10:57:58,700 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.util.IDPCredentials] (default task-1) Generando credenciales
10:57:58,700 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.util.IDPCredentials] (default task-1) EntityID and role input were supplied but no RoleDescriptorResolver is configured
10:57:58,700 INFO  [es.caib.accfor.api.util.IDPCredentials] (default task-1) Credenciales creadas
10:57:58,702 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ucm/accfor-api/receiverPage: net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.logic.ConstraintViolationException: Validation credential cannot be null
```

The question is why i dont see any trace in the log of this block?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can't find in your SourceCode any single line of code logging such a message like "Verificando firma"...."adquiriendo firma"....  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `catch(Exception e){}` <-- that is an empty catch block you have there. obviously nothing can be executed there. And most probably this line throw the error: `new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("IDPMetadata.xml").toURI());` I guess that the file does not exist where you think it is

Comment: You're getting an exception. Why don't you log the exception?

Comment: Imagine what happens if the line `File metadataFile = ...` throws an Exception. Exactly: nothing. Because you ignore the Exception.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ This is because this trace come from another class. The consumer class. The key is the jump in the log between "Reciviendo metadatos" and "metadatos resueltos"

Comment: Ok thnk u all. So easy!! The answer is im retard! If i dont catch the exception, and i have an exception, i cant know it. Thnk u all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the code matches the deployed version of your code?
If you can, launch the application locally and set a debug breakpoint in your IDE. I would also recommend to log in the catch block. I assume the culprit is the first line in the try body that throws an exception and the catch block silently captures it.

```
        try {
        File metadataFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("IDPMetadata.xml").toURI());
    }catch(Exception e){
        // log the exception
    }
```

Since the log statement after that line is not present but the log statement after the try block is, it is evident that the File access fails.